# Problems redirecting from jQuery dialog using Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, dialog

It's a pretty simple scenario, but I'm stuck...

I am popping up a jQuery UI dialog where the users enters some data.  I'm processing that data on the server, setting some session data attributes with it, and then returning a String value that matches the name of one of my JSP files.

Spring is detecting the string, finding the JSP via the viewresolver, and passing back the content of the JSP...but it's not loading.

Here's the view resolver, but I don't expect it's the issue...

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

...and here's the Controller redirect:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectSystem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String selectSystem(
        @RequestParam("systemid") Integer systemid,
        HttpSession session) {      
    session.setAttribute("currentSystem", systemid);
    return "system_main";
}
```

I've been watching this in Chrome's debugging tools.  The dialog sends the correct parameters, closes after the $.post is done and the server returns the JSP I expect with the jqGrid on it.  The page, though, is still sitting where I started.

Here's the dialog's AJAX posting the parameter to the server, and closing:

```
buttons: {
    Select: function () {
        $.post('selectSystem.html',"systemid="+jQuery('#systemsReviewGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'));
        dialog.remove();
    }
},
```

I tested not closing my dialog in case the content was going there before I closed it, but no change there.

The browser is showing the content in the Response data....so why isn't it rendering?  To make things more maddening, I'm doing a redirect to this exact same JSP in another area of the same controller and it works fine.  The only difference I can spot is that in that case the client isn't originating from a dialog...

Any thoughts on other areas to look?  Suggestions on other snippets to add here?

[EDIT:  Added some code descriptions to help provide context]

Comment: I see you are POSTing something but are you actually doing something with the response (rendered JSP)?

Comment: Alright, so the issue looks like a bad approach.  I'm using AJAX to post a value, then replying with a full JSP page.  What's the best way to utilize the whole new DOM?  Should I try to make the jQuery dialog button work like a form submit?  Is there a standard practice here?

Comment: If you need to refresh the entire page on submit then a regular form submit (post-redirect-get) is probably fine.

Comment: how about doing a window.location call and passing the parameter from my dialog?

Comment: yes that would do, on getting the response, do window.location.href to some controller method that will return the view. Btw, why do you have selectSystem method marked GET when you are doing a POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a lack of doing anything with the response.  In my ignorance I thought the browser would interpret the full DOM response and render the page.  It required a page shift like an href or form submit to cause the new page to render properly.

I ended up electing to use a window.location.href call with my parameters in the URL followed by the Spring controller returning the JSP after processing the parameters.  Worked like a champ.

Thanks for the comments.